# how much voltage pass through antenna?

Tags: voltage, antenna, field-strength

I want to know how much maximum voltage can be generated on a receiving antenna.

Also, please help me to find an antenna design with maximum received signal voltage; I dont have proper knowledge of antenna.

Comment: Voltage doesn't "pass through" anything.  The rest of your question doesn't make any more sense either.  We speak English here, not Gibberish.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but generally speaking, the signal level at the receiver input is on the order of a few microvolts.

Comment: How are we supposed to answer this ? A receiving antenna can deal with microvolts as well as kilovolts depending on the application. You have to be more specific.

Comment: *I dont have proper knowledge of antenna*  To solve this, books have been written by people who have a better understanding of antennas than you do. You might want to read one or more of these books instead of asking here.

Answer (score 7):

The voltage at an antenna's feedpoint is a function of the feedpoint impedance, and the power received by the antenna. Power (P), impedance (Z), and voltage (E) are related by the equation:

$$ E = \sqrt{ZP} $$

Typically the feedpoint impedance is purely resistive, so you can replace "impedance (Z)" with "resistance (R)" and the statement remains true.

There's no standard feedpoint impedance. Typically the feedpoint impedance is designed to match the characteristic impedance of the feedline. Coax feedlines are usually 50Ω or 75Ω. Twin-lead feedlines might have impedances of 200Ω or 300Ω. Waveguides have other impedances.

The power received by the antenna can be calculated with the [Friis transmission equation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/1539/218).

Assuming you can not alter the transmitter, or the distance between receiver and transmitter, the receiving antenna with the [highest gain](http://www.antenna-theory.com/basics/gain.php) will have the most power, and consequently highest voltage (subject to variations in impedance) at the feedpoint.

In typical practice, voltage at the feedpoint is on the order of a few microvolts at the receiving antenna. Variations in both directions exist, of course. The power received by GPS receivers is an order of magnitude smaller, and an antenna very near a high power transmitter could be an order of magnitude higher.

Comment: I think your last sentence should read: The power received by GPS receivers is an order of magnitude smaller, and an antenna very near a high power transmitter could be several orders of magnitude higher. - if you get a high-gain antenna close enough to a high-powered radar transmitter, for instance, you could probably generate arcs across your feedpoint contacts ;)

Answer (score 2):

This question is actually more broad than I think you imagined when you asked it, but I'll try to give you at least a starting point to figure out how to achkeve what you're looking for.

1. The voltage developed on a receiving antenna is a function of the [field strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_strength) of the signal being received, the [antenna impedance/gain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_measurement#Calculation_of_antenna_parameters_in_reception) and the [resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance) of the antenna at the frequency of the signal being received.
2. To develop maximum received signal voltage, you would want an antenna with high feedpoint impedance and high gain, designed/tuned to the frequency you're wanting to receive. One antenna design which might work well for you is the [cubic quad](http://www.qsl.net/yt1vp/CUBICAL%20QUAD%20ANTENNA%20CALCULATOR.htm) style antenna. Most cubic quads are designed with ~200ohms of source impedance, and you can easily achieve good resonance & gain with a properly designed "quad."

For further information on & exploration of this subject, the book: ["Practical Antenna Handbook"](http://www.arrl.org/shop/Practical-Antenna-Handbook-McGraw-Hill) is **required reading**.